# Invisible text in terminal after killing subprocess

Tags: c, multithreading, terminal

Let's take this snippet as an example:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { // Child
        execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
    } else if (pid > 0) { // Parent
        int n = atoi(argv[2]);
        sleep(n);
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);
        int status;
        wait(&status);
        ...
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After being run with `main [command] [seconds]`, the program should create a subprocess to execute the given command and terminate it after n seconds.

Problem is, if I call it with args `top 3` it correctly starts top and terminates after 3 seconds, but i'm left with a working shell with invisible text: i can type and execute commands, but the typed text doesn't show on the screen until a `reset` is run.

Any insight on what's happening?

Comment: OT: the error condition (pid < 0) is not being handled

Comment: OT: regarding: `int pid = fork();`  This should be: `pid_t pid = fork();`

Comment: OT: after this statement: `execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);`  Should have: `perror( "execlp failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: this statement: `return 0;` will never be executed unless there was an error in the call to `fork()` but the current code fails to let the user know of the error

Comment: @user3629249 All you said is correct. I removed some of the code to highlight the main logic, dont think error handling is relevant for the question. Any idea on the main issue?

Comment: suggest the first three parameters to `execlp()` be `/bin/bash` and `bash` and `-c`

Comment: @user3629249 Why? execlp uses the system path, no need to specify /bin/bash

Comment: because a new shell will be executed (in the background) and that is what needs to be terminated.  Otherwise the result of the call will be a 'interactive' shell

Comment: in your question, you did not mention that you had stripped off the error handling, so I am left to assume that you never wrote the error handling.  That is why I mentioned it

Comment: since execlp() uses the system search path, the first parameter can be reduce to : `bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` sets the terminal to a mode where it doesn't echo input (see `man noecho` or `man tcsetattr`). If `top` exits cleanly, like when you press "q" interactively, it resets it to a normal mode. But your program kills it, so the terminal is left in no-echo mode.

Comment: As a side note, running 3 ncurses programs at once might trigger unexpected/undefined behavior in the terminal, as all 3 will be sending control sequences to change the terminal state.

Comment: Actually (looking at Debian), **`top`** is a [*termcap*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library) application (it doesn't use ncurses to change the terminal modes, but only uses it for moving the cursor).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @ThomasDickey, I made my answer a little more generic and added a reference to `tcsetattr`.